# How to drag window from anywhere on the window without using the title bar?

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm, ui

I have made iTerm borderless, like this:

[image: Image of iTerm window]

So, how can I move the window from anywhere inside the window and not just the title bar?

Comment: How did you make Terminal borderless?

Comment: @user3439894 I am using iTerm 3 which has an option to hide borders

Comment: @adb16x its [iterm2 v3](https://iterm2.com/version3.html) not iTerm3

Comment: Just an additional tip, if you make the iterm2 borderless (no title bar) then window management tools like [rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) will not be able to position iterm2 either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To move any window, including borderless ones such as iTerm, you can move the mouse to any edge of the window until the cursor become a double-arrow, then click and hold while moving the mouse in a direction opposite of what would change the window size.

As an example, if you mouse over the top edge while the cursor is a double-arrow then click, hold and drag upwards or downwards it makes the window larger or smaller respectively, however if you drag left or right the window moves and once moving you can drag it anywhere and then release the mouse when you have the window where you want it.

The same paradigm applies on any edge of the window, moving the mouse to any edge, to where the cursor becomes a double-arrow then click and hold, and move in a direction that will not make the window larger or smaller will move the window instead.

---

**Update:**

This answer was originally posted on Nov 21 '16 and the target OS was OS X 10.11 El Capitan and works as stated for that OS.

There have been recent comments about it on macOS High Sierra and if the Title Bar is showing then it can be moved as described however if the Title Bar is not showing then it can only be moved in the manner described from the top of the window. That said though I've noticed it can be a bit finicky but I can move it as described when tested under macOS 10.13.3 in reference to this update notice.

Comment: Wow. I suspect that's not what they had in mind when they designed that particular feature.  That said, good thinking.

Comment: Does this still work as of High Sierra? I'm having trouble

Comment: @KyleHeuton it is working for me on 10.13.3 (tried with Firefox, chrome, and Preview)

Comment: @Michael I wonder if it's iTerm then, I still can't move it

Comment: @KyleHeuton I'm not sure how to make it borderless, but I am also observing that the dragging from edges other than top is NOT working in iTerm

Comment: Also works on macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: You can't do this if iterm2 is configured with a fixed-size window.

Comment: @alex, how do you fix the size of a _window_ in **iTerm2**?

Comment: I fixed this by changing the Window settings in Profile from `Fullscreen` to `Normal`.

Answer (score 9):

macOS has the ability to mouse move windows natively, it just happens to be disabled by default.

From Terminal:

```
defaults write -g NSWindowShouldDragOnGesture -bool true
```

Then log out/in or reboot for the setting to take effect.

Once rebooted, you can press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd> and **left-click** inside *most* windows and drag to move it.

To stop this behavior, you can delete this `defaults` setting from Terminal:

```
defaults delete -g NSWindowShouldDragOnGesture
```

Then log out/in or reboot for the change to take effect.

---

Note: This setting has worked since OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not work for my target: Alacritty.

Comment: It will work for Alacritty, but depends upon the `window`: `decorations` setting. It works for me with `buttonless`, `transparent`, and `full` but will *not* work with `none`.